# Retrieving Docusign envelop and recipient report

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docusign,  I would like to create a custom report that will include columns from the envelop report and recipient report, if we use the console.

Is there a service that will provide the report's column like "Remaining Signatures",  "# of Signers",  "# of Completed Signatures"?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, are you asking if you can customize columns in the report through the DocuSign Console?  Or are you asking something else, like if you can get column data through the API?

Comment: Absolutely!!!
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing DocuSign does not have any APIs that would allow you to customize or let you pull down columns from one of your account reports.